# How to create a serial number based save system for a java text based game?

Tags: java

So, let's say I wanted to save the following stats, as an example.

Intelligence,

inventory, (the object instance as a whole, with the strings found inside it and what not)

Gold.

My idea is to simply use a seed method, like in minecraft, yknow?

state of current game = (random 8 letter code, generated when you press the save and quit button.)

To load the game, just input the code. (Or maybe a way to keep that seed after the application is closed? Perhaps codding the app to make a folder with the codes in a txt file or something, and then taking the seeds from there?

Sorry if my question's confusing, and I didn't put any code in because I couldn't find anything matching what I'm looking for here Q_Q

Thanks again!

Comment: That's not a seed, it's a randomly generated filename. Minecraft's world seeds are different: they are used to generate the world algorithmically: they don't encode the player's current inventory or stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a string... it depends on how much data you need to save.

For starters, a random string won't work (I mean... maybe with some really (like, REALLY) complicated maths...?). It's way easier just to make all of the different characters represent certain values and work from there.

Firstly, you need to figure out how many bits you need to store the current state of your game. This would include things like, the current room/level/page that the player is in, how much health/money/etc the player has, and so on.

Next, you need to choose which characters can be used. To make life easy, you want 2^N different characters (lines up with binary). Hexdecimal works really nicely for this (0-9, A-F), as each character can be used to represent exactly 4 bits of data (see: Hexdecimal and binary representation of numbers).

Using hex, you could have up to 32 bits of data in an 8 character string - if that's enough for your game, then you could easily handle saves using simple hexdecimal strings.

---

For example; let's say you were making say, one of those game-books, and want to store a page number from 0-200, health from 0-10, and gold from 0-1000. This would mean, 2 characters for page number, 1 for health, and 3 for money. For example, at page 16 with 3 health and 854 money, this would translate to;

`page: 16, health: 3, money: 623 => 10 - 3 - 26F = 10326F`

Conversely, 28A2F0 would translate into;

`28A2F0 = 28 - A - 2F0 = level: 40, Health: 10, money: 752`

Of course, this is also very easy for the player to see how it works, so you may also want to use a simple algorithm to obfuscate the data (i.e, jumble up the order of the characters, use 16 random characters instead of conventional hexdecimals, etc).

Comment: A great way to look at it, I never considered bytes and stuff...
I'll definitely need to look into this ^_^

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to implement save/load feature in this kind of game would be to create a text file and write the stuff you want to save in there.

This first line of the text file would be your gold, second line would be your intelligence etc.. The program will go through each line, one by one, until it would find the line that would read "inventory:". Every line after that would be an item in inventory.

Basically, the first line would be always gold, the second line would always be HP and from the third line until the end of the file would be items in your inventory.

The way minecraft loads a world, using seed is a bit more complicated than that and wouldnt work with actual saving/loading.

Comment: I clarify, the seed in Minecraft is used to generate the world, not to keep track of the state of the game (health, inventory etc). You can generate the same world with the same seed, but all other information is saved in separate files like how @PotatoIng_ describes

Comment: Oh ok, glad you cleared that up ^_^ It's fascinating how all this works. So I suppose I could do the following:

Save all of the current data into a txt file,

Generate a code to title this txt file, or maybe a name creation thing, some kind of identifier,

Then just call this txt file at boot up and overwrite it whenever there's a change.

Or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: @Codster youre understanding it completely:3. I would reccomend asking user, what he wants to name his file and save it named like that. When the user then starts your game, you can ask him which file would he like to load. That way, you can have multiple save files You can even list all the files, in your saves folder and ask the user, which one would he like to laod. (Also, you dont have to save it as a ".txt" you can save it as ".anything", I dont know why, but I really like that)

Comment: To name the txt file would be something like,

string str = JTextField.getText();


code to create txt file.setTitle(str);

Not like like that but the general idea